# nodejs, socket.io and expressjs not connecting

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I have a folder structure like:

```
socket
  - project
    - main.js

  -node_modules
    - node_modules_folder_here

  - text.html
```

My main.js file looks like:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    console.log("inside")
    res.send('<h1>Hello again</h1>');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log("socket")
    console.log('a user connected');
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

I am running the server using `node main.js` and everything works fine
My test.html looks like:

```
<body>
<h3>Hellooww world</h3>
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var socket = io();
  console.log("check io", socket)
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

My package.json like:

```
"author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.24.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.4.0",
    "express": "^4.15.2",
    "node-fetch": "^1.6.3",
    "promise": "^7.1.1",
    "socket.io": "^1.7.3",
    "webpack": "^2.2.1",
    "xmlhttprequest": "^1.8.0"
```

I simply followed `socket.io` tutorial and got this error

```
GET file:///socket.io/socket.io.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
test.html:10 Uncaught ReferenceError: io is not defined
```

Also what if I am using this socket server for another project how to call it ?

What is the issue here ? I am simply following the socket.io tutorial and what am I mising here ? What is wrong and why ??

Comment: Install socket.io using npm

Comment: I have installed it.... I am running the server and it is fine there when I call it on html it gives error on there only

Comment: Did you add it to your package.json?

Comment: Try adding a reference <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>

Comment: yup.. server runs fine using node main.js .. I get everything I did on console.log except the once in socket connection in above code

Comment: @Aryan, try deleting the `node_modules` folder and install it again by writing `npm install` in the command line.

Comment: @Eldho  updated the question with package.json

Comment: @Ruben what if I use html from another folder or anywhere else

Comment: I don't see anywhere that you are serving your HTML file from your server.  You need to be loading the HTML file from your web server not from the file system.  So, you will need to make a handler on your web server ot server your HTML file and then you will need to load the web page from your web server.

Answer (score 0):

Your browser is looking for `file:///socket.io/socket.io.js`, the fact that it assumed file:// protocol makes me think that you are opening your html file directly.
You also have a missing quote after that src string.

Make sure you are loading `localhost:3000`.

Comment: Not having quote was type... I have started a dev server with python and opened my test.html ... Now it is only giving io is not defined error .. What is the isseu ?

Comment: @aryan check your web inspector and see if the HTTP call that requests socket.io.js is correctly returning 200. If it's not, then the browser isn't able to set up socket.io before executing your code.